# Set ORDER BY dynamically without string concatenation

Tags: sql-server, node.js, t-sql

I'm ussing [mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql) in a Express app to query a database.

My code is:

```
router.get('/expedientes', function (req, res, next) {
  request.input('pageSize', sql.Int, parseInt(req.query.page_size));
  request.query('SELECT TOP (@pageSize) * FROM expedientes', function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    res.send(result.recordset);
  });
});
```

I want to add a 'order dy' feature to the route. 
I've tried (with no luck) this:

```
router.get('/expedientes', function (req, res, next) {
  request.input('pageSize', sql.Int, parseInt(req.query.page_size));
  request.input('orderBy', sql.Text, req.query.order_by);
  request.input('orderDir', sql.Text, req.query.order_dir);
  request.query('SELECT TOP (@pageSize) * FROM expedientes ORDER BY (@orderBy) (@orderDir)', function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    res.send(result.recordset);
  });
});
```

How can I do this withouht using string concatenation? The docs aren't clear about this feature.

Comment: You can't parameterize the `ORDER BY` directly - since you can't parameterize identifiers or keywords. You can use case expressions in the order by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT TOP (@pageSize) * 
FROM expedientes 
ORDER BY CASE 
               WHEN @OrderBy = 'col1' AND @orderDir = 'ASC' THEN col1     
               --all columns in THEN part should have the same datatype
               WHEN @OrderBy = 'col2' AND @orderDir = 'ASC' THEN col2
               --  ...
         END,

         CASE 
               WHEN @OrderBy = 'col1' AND @orderDir = 'DESC' THEN col1     
               --should have the same datatype
               WHEN @OrderBy = 'col2' AND @orderDir = 'DESC' THEN col2
               --  ...
         END DESC
--OPTION(RECOMPILE);  -- to avoid expressions in final execution plan
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21f3d9416fe99bb8e512c4a177d6cf21)**